# apt-get error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I have error in apt-get install 
it is a error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I try several command
like: apt-get -f install
      apt-get clean

I try change my source list, and remake apt-get update

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

in apt-get -f install

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 434 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1.148 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6.333 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 194963 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You may find more help on http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: Do you use unstable or testing repositories? If so, define it manually: `apt-get -t unstable install ... `

Answer (score 25):

The same *dpkg* error is also possible when uninstalling:

```
apt-get uninstall
```

and

```
apt-get purge
```

First, uninstall the package:

```
rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package-name>*
apt-get purge <package-name>
```

Afterwards you can re-install it:

```
apt-get install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this. Open a new terminal and paste it

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
```

After that type:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Lastly type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps from the **terminal** :

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove libc6-dev-amd64 

 sudo apt-get -f install

 sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this will fix your issues.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-amd64

Answer (score 3):

none of the solutions i could find solved the problem for me...still broken packes, no matter the autoremove, `-f install` ... and so forth.

After playing around a little, the following solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 gcc-5-multilib gcc-multilib

sudo apt autoremove -f

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu on WSL. I didn't know which package broke my system, but it was probably one of those removed by the first command here.

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution, because the others quoted below did not work. Generally, it is a conflict with a dependency already installed.

I solved this problem with these command for recreate blank configuration (debian) :

- `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_silent`
- `sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get -f install <xxxx>`

Answer (score 1):

Try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed `libc6-dev-amd64` and you are trying to install packages that depend on `libc6-dev-i386`, and these two are in conflict (they both contain **/usr/include/bits**).

My guess is you don't want both of these installed at the same time.  I would use `apt-get remove libc6-dev-amd64` to get yourself back to a good state, and then try again to install the packages that you want.

If those two packages are meant to work when they're both installed at the same time, then file a bug with the package maintainer because they need to fix the packages to allow that.

Comment: i try remove the package, but i have the same error that have when try install g++

Answer (score 0):

When the upgrade command (`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`) is run in Ubuntu 18.04.3 (With Linux kernel version 5.7.14) the following errors get reported (in red):

```
... bind /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock: No such file or directory
... Fatal could not create server socket /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock
...
... Failed to start Agent daemon for Spice guests.
```

**The following steps fixed the issue:**

1. Make `spice-vdagentd` directory if it does not exist:

```
> sudo mkdir /var/run/spice-vdagentd (if it does not exist)
```

2. Open a new file `spice-vdagent-sock`

```
> sudo vi /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock
```

3. Save the file by running: `:wq`
4. Re-run the `upgrade` command to verify that the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Using below steps my problem resolve in "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager"

1. apt autoremove
2. apt purge libreoffice-base libreoffice-core
3. dpkg -l "*libreoffice*" | grep "^ii"
4. sudo dpkg --configure -a
5. sudo apt-get install -f

now you can try to install - pip3 install jupyter etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this problem with this command:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
python3-uno libreoffice-*
```

Comment: Before anyone trys a command like this ensure you check what else will be removed during this process, if you don't like what is being removed then say No.

You can purge things 1 at a time.
Not saying this is wrong, but these answers can mess up systems.