# Not able to install packages on mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dpkg

I just booted in Linux Mint a day ago, now the problem is I'm not able to install any package with apt.
Everytime I try to install a package I get the following error message:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried all the possible answer on ubuntu forums, stackoverflow or some particular blogs, related to this error. Some of those are:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131062
[apt-get error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677470/apt-get-error-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)
https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/
and many more, but none of those answers resolved my issue.
I posted this question on [linux mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=287423) forum too, but didn't get any useful response.
One thing I noticed that each time it throws the error

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test: not found
dpkg:
```

So I searched for this problem too but didn't get any useful results. When I manually checked for this file then the folder `nux` is not there.
Please help me with this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try [unix.se] or [su]? This question isn't about programming so is off-topic here

Comment: This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [sf] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.