# Facing error while installation of any software E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, apt-get, dpkg

I need help to fix this problem:
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3
python3-defer
python3-distro-info
python3-pkg-resources
python3-dbus
python3-aptdaemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

While installation everytime I receive this error, due to which I am unable to
I tried many solutions available but nothing worked for me.

Thank you for help in advance.

I tried 4 methods available on this [itsfoss url](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) but nothing worked as well as tried solution available on [stackoverflow url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677470/apt-get-error-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)